# Where can I find documentation for OpenAI's Whisper?

Tags: flutter, openai-whisper

I wanted to use Whisper and integrate it into my Flutter project. However, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do so. I am not even sure if Whisper can be used in Flutter. Any suggestions/advice on this, or any links or suggested videos on this would be greatly helpful.

I have been trying to look for documentation on Whisper and any info on how to integrate it with Flutter, can't seem to find anything on the web except this: https://pub.dev/packages/whisper_dart

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is the [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/). If you search for "OpenAI's Whisper", you should find the [dart_openai](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_openai) which should contain all the needed info, including the [documentation](https://github.com/anasfik/openai/blob/main/README.md) and the [API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/dart_openai/latest/):

[image]